# Passing an array as a function parameter in JS ES5

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm creating a directive for the `jQuery jstree plugin`.

This is how a `jstree` function is called (for example : `get_path` and `check_node`) :

```
get_path (obj, glue, ids)
check_node (obj)
```

In my directive post link function I pass some actions that I want to be executed in the jstree init, so I pass an object like this:

```
vm.initActions = {
    check_node: [nodesToCheck],
    get_path: [obj, glue, ids]
};
```

And then to execute those function :

```
if(scope.initActions){
    Object.keys(scope.initActions).forEach(function(action){
        if(scope.treeView.jstree(true).hasOwnProperty(action)){
            scope.treeView.jstree(true)[action].apply(this, scope.initActions[action]);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass an array as the function parameter so it would be like this:

```
scope.treeView.jstree(true).check_node(nodesToCheck);
scope.treeView.jstree(true).get_path(obj, glue, ids);
```

But this is not working I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

And this is the source if the error (jstree.js) :

```
this.check_node = function (obj, e) {
            if(this.settings.checkbox.tie_selection)
```

In the other hand the spread operator is working fine:

```
if(scope.initActions){
    Object.keys(scope.initActions).forEach(function(action){
        if(scope.treeView.jstree(true).hasOwnProperty(action)){
            scope.treeView.jstree(true)[action](...scope.initActions[action]);
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately I can't use the spread operator because I'm tied to use ES5.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `scope.treeView.jstree(true)` instead of `this` as the first argument to `apply` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method of the function:

```
var context = scope.treeView.jstree(true);
context[action].apply(context, scope.initActions[action]);
```